# How to Strip off HTML Element and its Inner Text Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace inline script injection by replacing  tag with  and then I want to remove whole  tag along with its inside text. I am struggling to remove  tag as a whole. Any help would be highly useful. This what I was able to achieve-

```js
$(".txtScript").live("blur", function () {
        stripScriptTags();
    });
function stripScriptTags() {
    var wrappedString = $(".txtScript").val();
    var noScript = wrappedString.replace(/script/g, "THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY");
    var html = $(noScript);
    html.find('THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY').remove();
}
```

The Input which I am passing is-

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><script type="Text/JavaScript">alert('hello')</script>Success</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Expected Output-

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Success</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do you want to update the text box value by removing the script tag in it?

Comment: Do you have an html markup?

Comment: @RaviNila Yes I want to remove script tag and the alert text and keep only simple text like “Test Success”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `.replace(/script/g)` with jQuery. But if you prefer RegExp, consider using `i` flag along with `g` for the insensitive case.

Also, jQuery adds some additional tags, e.g. `<tbody>` and it's slower compared to RegExp. I don't recommend this way.

**jQuery only:**

```js
$('.txtScript').on('blur', stripScriptTags);

function stripScriptTags() {
  var wrappedString = $(this).val();
  var $html = $(wrappedString);

  $html.find('script').remove();

  $('#result').text($html[0] && $html[0].outerHTML || '');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="txtScript"></textarea>  
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

**With RegExp:**

```js
$('.txtScript').on('blur', stripScriptTags);

function stripScriptTags() {
  const regex = /\<script(.*)\/script\>/gi;
  $('#result').text($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="txtScript"></textarea>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks artanik the only difference is instead of using const variable I am storing the pattern and attribute in var type JS variable.